# Checking 2 int variables

Tags: python

I have 2 `int` variables.  One contains user input, and the other is a computer generated number (0,99).

How can I check if the input variable contains a digit that is also in the computer generated numbers?

For a first example, if the user enters 45 and the computers guess was 54?

Or, if the user guesses one of the digits correctly, like, the user guesses 23, and the computer guess is 35?

```
Guess = int(input("Please guess a number between 0 to 99:"))
if Guess <= 99 and Guess >= 0:
    break
except ValueError:
    print("")
RandomNum = random.randint(0,99)
print("Random Generated Number",RandomNum)
if RandomNum == Guess:
    print("Jackpot!! You win 100 !")
if RandomNum == Guess[0,1]:
    print("Right Digits,wrong order. You win 10")
```

Comment: can you be more specific on what you are asking?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show your own code and explain what difficulties you are having?

Comment: @Zachtakk Edit your question and put that code in there and use the formatting tools. Posting code in comments is illegible.

Comment: And please explain what is wrong with your code. What are you trying to do in your code and how is it behaving that leads you to believe it is not working.

Comment: @idjaw probably the `TypeError` ;)

Comment: Half of the lines in your code are wrong - some of them extremely so. You need to study more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you want to check if the user's number contains the same digit as the computer-generated numbers.

If you only ever going to have two digits numbers you can get away with 
`if str(RandomNum) == str(Guess)[::-1]:`. This will check if the string value of `RandomNum` is equal to the string value of `Guess` in reverse.

If you want a more generalized solution then first you will need to define the desired behavior.